# How to fix broken scroll on site

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

so I am editing a friends site, and they originally did not have a visible scroll bar, although they now want it to be visible. From my understanding, changing

```
overflow: hidden;
```

inside of the body to

```
overflow: scroll;
```

should fix this.

However, I have changed this code from hidden to scroll, and the page has become locked, and I can no longer scroll. I have also tried using auto. The code inside the body is here:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    &.touch, &.firefox {
        main {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            &.locked {
                overflow-y: hidden;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, you have the tag JavaScript attached to your question, is there any JS involved in the scrolling issue? If you remove this entire block of SCSS code does the scroll bar show up?

Comment: what is the context of 'locked' class in the html page?

Comment: On the fifth/sixth line of css, maybe change `overflow: visible;` to `overflow: scroll;`? I'm not entirely sure. Test: https://jsfiddle.net/nukeboy212/z2obx7qr/3/

Comment: @JALO-JusAnotherLivngOrganism I am afraid I don't understand your question

Comment: @thespeciamone yeah I tried this already, I have also tried changing it to "overflow-x" and "overflow-y" and it results in the page being locked (unable to scroll).

Comment: @LondonMassive it seems to work just fine: Test: https://jsfiddle.net/nukeboy212/z2obx7qr/3/

Comment: When I leave it as "overflow: hidden;", I can scroll up and down the page but the bar is not visible when I change it to anything other than "hidden" I cannot scroll

Comment: @thespeciamone I just tried out your link and yeah that works, thing is "overflow: hidden;" is found in many places within the sites files, and I have tried changing all "hidden" ones to "scroll" and I am left with the same result, being unable to scroll.

Comment: Oh, try adding !important to the end of it. `overflow: scroll !important;`

Comment: @thespeciamone yeah, unfortunately, this just does the same thing, the scroll bar is visible for a second the screen is locked and I can't scroll

Comment: Could you make a fiddle with all the code? It seems that there is something blocking it then.

Comment: @thespeciamone a fiddle? File?

Comment: Sorry, I was reffering to jsfiddle.net. You can easily plug in your css, html, and js

Comment: @thespeciamone I think I have done it right https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=4vUyPqQIxp

Comment: Thing is, I just tested the code on that jsfiddle, and it works, so I think there must be something in some other classes causing the problem @thespeciamone